# Does a vector space and its dual contain the same number of elements?

Tags: vector-spaces, dual-spaces

I'm pretty sure if we're talking the vector space $\Bbb{R}^3$ the number of vectors in this space is infinite, but does the dual space of $\Bbb{R}^3$ have a one-to-one correspondence with its vector space?

Have mercy on my mathematical abilities in any answers please; I'm not a mathematician.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If we're talking about *finite* dimensional vector spaces, then the answer is *yes*. The correspondence is actually a really common object.

In particular, given two vectors, $\langle x_1,y_1,z_1\rangle$ and $\langle x_2,y_2,z_2\rangle$, their inner product (or dot product) is
$$\langle x_1,y_1,z_1\rangle \cdot \langle x_2,y_2,z_2\rangle = x_1x_2+y_1y_2+z_1z_2.$$
This is handy in all sorts of geometrical contexts, but, in relation to your question, this map has a handy property: it is bilinear, meaning that, if we fixed either vector, the function is linear in the other. For instance
$$\langle 1,2,4\rangle \cdot\langle x_2,y_2,z_2\rangle = x_2+2y_2+4z_2$$
is clearly a linear function of $\langle x_2,y_2,z_2\rangle$ and hence defines an element of the dual space of $\mathbb R^3$. Thus, we can map vectors $\langle x_1,y_1,z_1\rangle$ to the element of the dual space that takes $\langle x_2,y_2,z_2\rangle$ to $x_1x_2+y_1y_2+z_1z_2$. One can check that this is a one-to-one correspondence; the inverse map takes a map $f:\mathbb R^3\rightarrow \mathbb R$ in the dual space of $\mathbb R^3$ to the vector $$\langle f(\langle 1,0,0\rangle),f(\langle 0,1,0\rangle),f(\langle 0,0,1\rangle)\rangle$$
which basically just evaluates $f$ on the basis elements, then records those values which can, by linearity, reconstruct what $f$ must be on *every* element. Otherwise said, every linear function is given as the inner product between some fixed vector and the argument.

In very broad generality, this is exactly finite case of [the Riesz representation theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz_representation_theorem) (for Hilbert spaces). A Hilbert space is just a space that acts like $\mathbb R^n$ in that it has a sensible inner product and in which convergence works is a sensible way - and the argument given above extends easily to the *continuous* dual of such a space.

In broader generalizations, like just using vector spaces with no additional structure, the answer tends to be *no*. For instance, the dual of an infinite dimensional vector space has higher dimension than the original space - which is sort of surprising - and this implies that, as long as the dimension of the first space was infinite *enough*, the second space will not only have higher dimension (meaning no *linear* one-to-one correspondence exists), but will also have more elements (in the sense of cardinality - meaning absolutely no one-to-one correspondence exists).

Comment: How infinite is infinite enough?

Comment: @JairTaylor Well, if a vector space over a field $F$ has a basis $B$, then the space is isomorphic to the space of functions $B\rightarrow F$ with only finitely many non-zero values. Assuming the axiom of choice, that means that the space has cardinality $\max\{|B|,|F|\}$ when either is infinite. So "infinite enough" for the vector spaces not to be in bijection means that the dual space has dimension strictly greater than the cardinality of the field.

Comment: I see, so for $B$ infinite, we have $|V| = \max\{|B|, |F|\}$ while $|V^*| = |F|^{|B|}$, yes? So we require $|F|^{|B|} > \max\{|B|, |F|\}$. We always have $|F|^{|B|} >|B|$, since $2^{|B|} > |B|$, so we just need $|F|^{|B|} > |F|$, although I'm not quite sure when that occurs.

Comment: @JairTaylor Yes, exactly - I think you'd need to ask a set theorist to know whether that last inequality simplifies at all.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, and it is very general. For each basis $\{e_1,\dots, e_n\}$ in a $K$-vector space of dimension $n$ $V$, there exists a *dual basis* $\{\varepsilon _1,\dots,\varepsilon_n\}$ in $V^*$ defined by the conditions
\begin{cases}
\varepsilon _i(e_j)=0&\text{ if }i\ne j,\\
\varepsilon _i(e_i)=1&\text{ for all  }\,i.
\end{cases}
Mapping each $e_i$ onto $\varepsilon_i$ ($i=1,\dots, n$) defines an isomorphism from $V$ onto its dual.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Indeed, if $V$ is finite dimensional, then there is an isomorphism between $V$ and $V^*$ given by taking any basis $B = \{e_1,\ldots,e_n\}$ of $V$, and defining a basis $B^* = \{f_1,\ldots,f_n\}$ of $V^*$ given by $f_i(\sum a_j e_j) = a_i$, then having our isomorphism send each $e_i$ to $f_i$, and extend linearly from there.

In the infinite-dimensional case, the dual is not isomorphic: indeed, the dimension of $V^*$ is always of higher cardinality than that of $V$. Thus, we can have $|V| = |V^*|$ only in the cases where the cardinality of the dimension of $V$ is smaller than the cardinality of the base field (though it is not guaranteed there).